# Values of the wrong group are used when using plot() within a data.table() in RStudio

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio

I want to generate a divided diagram. On the upper section of the diagram the values of group `a`, on the lower one the values of group `b` should be used. I am using `data.table()` to do this. Here is the code I used to generate an example and set up the graphical output:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(23)
Example <- data.table('group' = rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 5), 'value' = runif(10))
layout(1:2)
par('mai' = rep(.5, 4))
```

When running the following lines in the usual r console the correct values are used for the plotting. When running the same code in Rstudio the values of the second group are used for both diagrams:

```
Example[, plot(value, ylim = c(0, 1)), by = group] # Example 1
Example[, .SD[plot(value, ylim = c(0, 1))], by = group] # Example 2
```

When adding a comma in the subset data.table `.SD[]` of example 2 the correct output is generated in Rstudio as well:

```
Example[, .SD[, plot(value, ylim = c(0, 1))], by = group] # Example 3
```

When using `barplot()` rather than `plot()` Rstudio uses the correct values as well:

```
Example[, barplot(value, ylim = c(0, 1)), by = group] # Example 4
```

Did I overlook something or is this a bug?

System: Windows 7, Rstudio Desktop v0.98.1091, R 3.1.2, data.table 1.9.4

Comment: All plots are generated correctly in my setup: Rstudio 0.98.1028, R 3.0.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice catch (+1'd already)! In my case, Example 3 doesn't produce the right plot as well (OS X 10.10.1, R 3.1.2, Rstudio 0.98.1091).

The only difference between R console/GUI and Rstudio here is the plotting device. RStudio seems to be using a native graphics device `RstudioGD`, where as R console / GUI uses `Quartz`.

By debugging `graphics:::plot.default` I was able to narrow down the issue to the function `plot.xy()`. This function calls different graphics devices (as shown above).

By initiating, for example, `Quartz` by calling the function `quartz()` and then running your code works fine!

FWIW this issue can be reproduced using `dplyr()` as well:

```
require(dplyr)
df = as.data.frame(Example)
my_fun = function(x) {plot(x, ylim=c(0,1)); 1L }
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(my_fun(value))
```

will result in the same wrong plot.

This is most likely due to the way the subgroups are handled in data.table (and I think `dplyr` should be doing it the same way as data.table), which you can see by:

```
Example[, print(sapply(.SD, address)), by=group]
#         value 
# "0x105bbf5b8" 
#         value 
# "0x105bbf5b8" 
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: group
```

`data.table` assigns the largest group for `.SD` and internally reuses this memory for each subgroup so as to avoid repetitive memory alloc/dealloc - for efficiency. Not sure (shooting in the dark here), but it seems like `RstudioGD` doesn't let go of the pointer linked with the subgroup, and as the data in the subgroup gets updated, the plot gets updated too. You can verify this by doing:

```
# on RstudioGD
debug(graphics:::plot.default)
set.seed(23)
Example <- data.table('group' = rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 5), 'value' = runif(10))
layout(1:2)
par('mai' = rep(.5, 4))
Example[, plot(value, ylim = c(0, 1)), by = group] # Example 1
undebug(graphics:::plot.default)
```

Keep hitting enter, and you'll see that the first plot is plotted right.. and when the second plot is added, the first plot changes as well. This may be a consequence of recent changes in Rv3.1+ which shallow copies function arguments rather than deep copying (again, shooting in the dark here).

You can temporarily fix this by explicitly copying `value`:

```
Example[, plot(copy(value), ylim = c(0, 1)), by = group] # Example 1
```

will produce the right plot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extensive answer and the hint to use copy(). This looks like the easiest fix at the moment.

Comment: In case this may be helpful @Arun, if I run Example 1 or 2 from the console I get the correct plot as Jonas said, but if I then print the plot or copy-as-metafile and then paste (e.g.into Word) I get the flawed plot. Copy-as-bitmap does not do this. Finally, try the example without ylim=c(0,1). When I print or copy I get the appropriate y range for each plot but the repeated last data - shifted partly off-scale in the first plot.

Comment: Windows 7, R 3.1.2, data.table 1.9.4