# Plotting by group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I've got individual-level data for which I'm trying to summarize an outcome dynamically by group.

Example:

```
set.seed(12039)
DT <- data.table(id = rep(1:100, each = 50),
                 grp = rep(letters[1:4], each = 1250),
                 time = rep(1:50, 100),
                 outcome = rnorm(5000))
```

I want to know the simplest way to plot the group-level summary, the data for which is contained in:

```
DT[ , mean(outcome), by = .(grp, time)]
```

I wanted something like:

```
dt[ , plot(mean(outcome)), by = .(grp, time)]
```

But this doesn't work at all.

The workable option I am surviving on (which could be looped pretty easily) is:

```
plot(DT[grp == "a", mean(outcome), by = time])
lines(DT[grp == "b", mean(outcome), by = time])
lines(DT[grp == "c", mean(outcome), by = time])
lines(DT[grp == "d", mean(outcome), by = time])
```

(with added parameters for colors, etc, excluded for conciseness)

This strikes me as not the best way to do this--given `data.table`'s craft in handling groups, is there not a more elegant solution?

Other sources have been pointing me to `matplot` but I can't see a straightforward way to use it--do I need to reshape `DT`, and is there a simple `reshape` that would get the job done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base **R** solution using `matplot` and `dcast`

```
dt_agg <- dt[ , .(mean = mean(outcome)), by=.(grp,time)]
dt_cast <- dcast(dt_agg, time~grp, value.var="mean")
dt_cast[ , matplot(time, .SD[ , !"time"], type="l", ylab="mean", xlab="")]
# alternative:
dt_cast[ , matplot(time, .SD, type="l", ylab="mean", xlab=""), .SDcols = !"time"]
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do this with `data.table`'s `by` argument as follows:

```
DT[ , mean(outcome), by = .(grp, time)
    ][ , {plot(NULL, xlim = range(time),
           ylim = range(V1)); .SD}
       ][ , lines(time, V1, col = .GRP), by = grp]
```

Note that the intermediate `{...; .SD}` part is necessary to continue chaining. If `DT[ , mean(outcome), by = .(grp, time)]` were already stored as another `data.table`, `DT_m`, then we could just do:

```
DT_m[ , plot(NULL, xlim = range(time), ylim = range(V1))]
DT_m[ , lines(time, V1, col = .GRP), by = grp]
```

With output

[image: data.table group by]

Much fancier results are possible; for example, if we wanted to specify specific colors for each group:

```
grp_col <- c(a = "blue", b = "black",
             c = "darkgreen", d = "red")
DT[ , mean(outcome), by = .(grp, time)
    ][ , {plot(NULL, xlim = range(time),
           ylim = range(V1)); .SD}
       ][ , lines(time, V1, col = grp_col[.BY$grp]), by = grp]
```

---

## NOTE

There is a bug in RStudio which will cause this code to fail *if the output is sent to the RStudio graphics device*. As such this approach only works from R on the command line or from sending the output to an external device (I sent it to `png` to produce the above).

See [`data.table` issue #1524](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1524), [this RStudio support ticket](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208778048-RStudioGD-has-some-bug-when-used-within-j-of-data-table-also-dplyr-), and these SO Qs ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413514/strange-error-plotting-by-group) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505794/values-of-the-wrong-group-are-used-when-using-plot-within-a-data-table-in-rs))

Answer (score 4):

You are very much on the right track. Use `ggplot` to do this as follows:

```
(dt_agg <- dt[,.(mean = mean(outcome)),by=list(grp,time)]) # Aggregated data.table
     grp time        mean
  1:   a    1  0.75865672
  2:   a    2  0.07244879
 ---
```

Now ggplot this aggregated data.table

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dt_agg, aes(x = time, y = mean, col = grp)) + geom_line()
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using reshape2 you can convert the dataset into something with means:

```
new_dt <- dcast(dt,time~grp,value.var='outcome',fun.aggregate=mean)

new_dt_molten <- melt(new_dt,id.vars='time')
```

and then plot it with ggplot2 like this:

```
ggplot(new_dt_molten,aes(x=time,y=value,colour=variable)) + geom_line()
```

Alternatively, (easier solution actually) you can use the dataset that you have directly and do something like:

```
ggplot(dt,aes(x=time,y=outcome,colour=grp)) + geom_jitter() + geom_smooth(method='loess')
```

or

```
ggplot(dt,aes(x=time,y=outcome,colour=grp)) + geom_smooth(method='loess')
```