# Receiving an unexpected error when plotting by group

Tags: r, plot, data.table

Sorry for the massive data dump but I can't reproduce this on the subsets of the data I've tried. Copy-pasted the `dput` of the data (165 obs., not crazy) to [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/MichaelChirico/f75d811de84284e1ca356ed67ac2cce2).

I'm trying to plot the data in `DT` by `sport`, according to:

1. Create empty plot with proper limits to accommodate all data
2. Plot the column `gini` as a scatterplot, with colors varying by `sport`
3. Plot the column `five_year_ma` as a line, with color matching that in 2.

This should be simple and I've done things like it before. Here's what should work:

```
#empty plot with proper axes
DT[ , plot(
  NA, ylim = range(gini), xlim = range(season), 
  xlab = "Season", ylab = "Gini",
  main = "Comparison of Gini Coefficient Across Sports"
)]

#pick colors for each sport
cols <- c(NHL="black", NBA="red")

DT[ , by = sport, {
  #add points to current plot
  points(season, gini, col = cols[.BY$sport])

  #add lines to current plot
  lines(season, five_yr_ma, col = cols[.BY$sport], lwd = 3)
}]
```

But this gives me output/error:

```
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: sport
```

> Error: `x` and `y` lengths differ in `plot.xy()`

This is strange. If we skip the grouping and just do it manually, it works perfectly fine:

```
all_sports[sport == "NBA", {
  points(season, gini, col = "red")
  lines(season, five_yr_ma, col = "red", lwd = 3)
}]

all_sports[sport == "NHL", {
  points(season, gini, col = "black")
  lines(season, five_yr_ma, col = "black", lwd = 3)
}]
```

[image: This plot shows the expected output. It is a scatterplot titled "Comparison of Gini Coefficient Across Sports. The x axis is titled "Season" and varies from 1920 to 2000. The y axis is titled "Gini" and varies from .05 to .2. There are black points and red points in the plotting area; from the code we infer that the black points correspond to NHL seasons, and the red to NBA seasons. Additionally, there are black and red lines (with the same correspondence in color as the points) superimposed over the points corresponding to the 5-year moving averages of the underlying points. There is a downward trend in the black line, and an upward trend in the red one.]

Moreover, even in the context of grouping, it's unclear why `plot.xy` has received arguments of different length -- if we make the following adjustment to force R to record the inputs just before they're sent, there doesn't appear to be any issue:

```
all_sports[ , {
  cat("\n\nPlotting for sport: ", .BY$sport)
  points(x1 <- season, y1 <- gini, col = cols[.BY$sport])
  lines(x2 <- season, y2 <- five_yr_ma, col = cols[.BY$sport], lwd = 3)
  cat("\npoints/season: ",length(x1),
      "\npoints/gini: ", length(y1),
      "\nlines/season: ", length(x2),
      "\nlines/five_yr_ma: ", length(y2))},
  by = sport]
```

Has output:

```
# Plotting for sport:  NHL
# points/season:  98 
# points/gini:  98 
# lines/season:  98 
# lines/five_yr_ma:  98

# Plotting for sport:  NBA
# points/season:  67 
# points/gini:  67 
# lines/season:  67 
# lines/five_yr_ma:  67
```

What could be going on??

---

Since it appears like this is not common across machines, here's my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rsconnect_0.4.1.11 tools_3.2.4
```

Comment: I ran your code with the same null data.table output, but no error. (Oh, and the graph worked fine.)

Comment: @Frank strange (but encouraging)... let me restart things...

Comment: works for me - try again in a fresh session?

Comment: @eddi still getting an error... adding session info... are you on the latest `devel` Frank or eddi?

Comment: Fwiw, 1.9.7 on 3.2.3 here.

Comment: 1.9.7, at least a couple months old, windows, 3.1.3

Comment: Just re-installed to freshest dev, still an error. Gonna try to install an older version... anyway seems like this is best filed as a bug at this point, thanks for the fresh runs.

Comment: @Frank you're on Windows right? Anyone getting a clean run on Linux?

Comment: I only get the black line and it doesn't really look anything like yours. when I go to zoom/resize, I get the lengths differ errors and the zoom doesnt show. mac/1.9.7

Comment: @rawr I just re-installed to [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/tree/2aba0c4bda8e4510ced1db85a766ab62f331c48e) commit from January 3 w same error, beginning to think it's a problem with R rather than `data.table`... are you on 3.2.4?

Comment: @MichaelChirico yessir

Comment: @rawr sounds like we have our culprit... just tried the CRAN version of `data.table`, same issue, so doesn't seem like it's something on `data.table` side (sort of makes sense, given what I've tried)

Comment: Not seeing anything in the change logs for 3.2.4 ([1](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2016/000597.html), [2](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2016/000598.html)) that seem like they'd have an effect on `plot.xy`....

Comment: I get the same behavior on a win7 running cran data table and 3.2.2

Comment: The saga continues...

Comment: Are you running it on RStudio? Have you tried from R console or R's GUI? I remember answering [other weirdness in Rstudio](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27509129/559784)...

Comment: @Arun good call, indeed RStudio may be the issue. Ran it from terminal without issue. Don't have time to read that thread right now, will follow up... Have for now isolated it to be an `RStudioGD` issue -- if I send the plot to, e.g., `png`, I don't get an error.

Comment: In the r gui, I get the image in your post. when I resize it, I get the image with only the black line/points (although it is not the same as in the image) and the length differ errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, as @Arun points out, it seems this is a resurfacing of the (as yet unsolved) issue which was causing the error in this question:

[Values of the wrong group are used when using plot() within a data.table() in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27505794/3576984)

As @Arun discovered there, it seems like RStudio's native graphics device is somehow getting tripped up by the changing pointers used for the different subgroups created when evaluating `j` when `by` is present, which lends itself to the workaround of simply `copy`ing all of `.SD` each time, like:

```
points(copy(season), copy(gini),
       col = cols[.BY$sport])
lines(copy(season), copy(five_yr_ma), 
      col = cols[.BY$sport], lwd = 3)
```

Or

```
x <- copy(.SD)
with(x, {points(season, gini, cols = cols[.BY$sport]);
         lines(copy(season), copy(five_yr_ma), 
           col = cols[.BY$sport], lwd = 3)})
```

Both of which worked for me (since the subgroups are so small, there's no computational efficiency concern at play here -- we can `copy` away without affecting performance noticeably).

This is [#1524](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1524) at the `data.table` GitHub page and I've filed [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208778048-RStudioGD-has-some-bug-when-used-within-j-of-data-table-also-dplyr-) bug report at RStudio Support; will update this if a fix is pushed.